# Headings under Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation, heading, drawer

How to add Headings in drawer layout. For example in YouTube application it has Headings in it's drawer like Subscription and from YouTube... So How we can add such Headings in Drawer Layout?

Check below image I want to add heading like "Subscription" used in this image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The magic is happening in the `Adapter` that is feeding views to the `ListView`.

When a `ListView` is scrolled, it has to display whatever row is next in the data set.  Instead of having to do this on their own, `ListView`s are backed by an `Adapter`.  The `ListView` essentially asks the adapter for the next view (naming an index value) every time it needs to scroll up or down.

The `Adapter` can pass the `ListView` whatever it wants.  When the `ListView` asks for row x (an index value), the `Adapter` can look at the data set and see that row x should be a special header.  The adapter builds or recycles a special header view and passes it to the list view.

See the [List View Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) for example code.